# Scroll bar missing after applying custom CSS

Tags: css

I am having problem when using custom CSS, the issue is scroll bars both horizontal and vertical will disappear when I use the custom CSS. i have tried IE, Chrome and Microsoft Edge and I am experiencing the issue with all the browser. its only happening when I try to edit Nintex Workflow.
Regards.
[image]

Comment: the browser console is your friend. not sure if this is related to sharepoint or nintex pages, but you can inspect the page and try to find out which changes are breaking the scroll on that particular page and then decide how to move forward. the question could benefit in added details and tags